# My code is returning the wrong if statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a simple code which will open a door for students above 18, but whatever number I input it always returns the wrong option in the if statement. 
Please see it below.

```py
Def checkStudentAge:
 Input("what is your name student?: ")

Age = 0

If int(age) < 18
 Print("this door only opens for students that are 18 are above")

elif int(age)  > 18
 Print(" you are welcome, please push the door and step in")

else int(age) ==18
 Print("congrats you can step in)

CheckStudentage()
```

Whenever I call the function, and input an int higher than 18, it still says " this door only opens for students 18 and above". I am new to python and this my first language,  I'd appreciate corrections

I did age = 0, because I want to assign a value to age incase no input is given

Comment: what is `Age = 0` for?

Comment: You set age to 0, not the result of the input call.

Comment: This isn't correct python code, since the 'I' in If should be lowercase, and each if, elif, else should have a : at the end of the line.

Comment: Also, it should be "you're welcome", not "your welcome"

Comment: `age = int( input(...) )`

Comment: Hi "Code newbie", welcome to StackOverflow! As what @magarnicle has stated, could you please clarify if what you've added to the question is pseudo-code or actual Python code (which I'm afriaid will probably not be interpreted properly). The other reason why your code probably isn't working is because your `input()` statement isn't assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def checkStudentAge():
  age = int(input("age: "))

  if age < 18:
    print('This door opens for students who are 18 or above')
  else:
    print('Welcome! Please push the door and step in')

  """ The if-else can also be combined into one line like so:

print('This door opens for students who are 18 or above') if age < 18 else print('Your are welcome, please push the door and step in')

  """
checkStudentAge()
```

The `elif` and `else` can be put into one `else` because either the age is [less than 18] or [greater than or equal to].

Comment: You can also do: `print('This door opens for students who are 18 or above') if int(input('Age: ')) < 18 else print('Your are welcome, please push the door and step in')`